# Which tense is this sentence?

Tags: tenses, sentence

Which tense is this sentence?: „I don‘t think I did very well in my exams.“

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence is a complex one.

In the main clause "I don‘t think" the verb is the Present Simple Tense.

In the relative clause "I did very well in my exams" the verb is The Past Simple Tense.